# Visualizing tasks completed by workers over time

Tags: data-visualization

I have several "workers"/"executors"/"agents" that process some "tasks" over time. The data about processed tasks can be presented in a table like this:

| Task # | Processed by | Time started | Time completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 12:00 | 12:10 |
| 2 | X | 12:15 | 12:30 |
| 3 | Y | 12:20 | 12:35 |
| 4 | Z | 12:25 | 12:40 |
| 5 | z | 12:30 | 12:40 |
| 6 | Y | 12:35 | 12:40 |
| 7 | Y | 13:00 | 13:30 |

I want to visualize it in some way like this (screenshot from manually colored Excel spreadsheet):

[image]

, *kinda* like Gantt chart - but each row (corresponding to worker) should contain many colored bars (corresponding to task and its execution time). Question is - how is this type of charts/diagrams even called? Or maybe it is possible to visualize the data with other (more "mainstream") charts in a way I have not thought about yet?

---

**NOTE:** The question is not about project management or planning, it is about ways to visualize "machine-provided" data. Specifically - I am looking for means to visualize build processing times on Jenkins automation server, in order to highlight problematic agents and bottlenecks and study their reasons.

Comment: Use project management software.

Comment: This comment neither answers question neither points to answer. The question is marked as "offtopic", but said link clearly states "visualizing data" among valid topics. I presume I tipped you off by mentioning "programming", but all I needed was a hint about which terms or what tool I should look for. Finally, it seems you presumed my problem was about managing people and tasks - while in fact it was about visualizing machine-generated data. Could you please reopen the question?

Comment: Asking for code or software is off-topic. If your question is "What is the name of this chart?" then please [edit] to ask about that alone.

Comment: One of the main uses of project management software is to produce charts like this. More importantly, good PM software provides the right tools to achieve your ultimate objective of understanding "problematic agents and bottlenecks," which would be on the *critical path* of the project.